# Can't Use Certain DataContext Commands Like '.Find' in Windows Application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

Forgive me if this is a really dumb question. I have a ASP.NET Code First Application (VB.NET 4.6) using DataContext in which I can use a syntax like this:

```
Dim db As New MyDataContext
Dim id As Integer = 123456
Dim clientRec = db.Clients.Find(id)
```

So now I am building a backend WinForm support for the ASP.NET FrontEnd and can't seem to find the right combination of references to make this work, OR if it is even possible. It seems like the DB commands are different in Windows Forms. I'm used to building WinForms so sure there are workarounds but I don't understand why there are differences and how I could close the gap if possible in order to use a similar command set. Thanks in advance for setting me straight!

Comment: Based on the syntax you have shown, the `Find` method is not a method on the `MyDataContext` class but on the `Clients` property.  What datatype is the `Clients` property?

Comment: `Clients` is a table created from CodeFirst. More info on *DbSet(Of TEntity).Find Method* HERE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg696418(v=VS.113).aspx). I guess that I'm just not understanding something enough to make the connection.